# How to use file path stored in a cell in another cell to refer to a value in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros, microsoft-excel-2016, trim

I have a macro that loads the path of a file to a cell dynamically, Let's say the cell is C1. C1 contains
File Path: "/a/x/c/s"

How do I use the value stored in C1 in other cells to get the path from C1 and add the tab name and the cell so I can reference the value in that file?

I tried using:

```
=TRIM([C1]tab1!$K$52)
```

where tab1 is the tab name and cell I want to get value from is K52 in that tab.
The formula above gives:

> #REF error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the format that you should use (you also need file name, not only path):

```
='C:\Temp\[test_file.xlsx]Sheet1'!K52
```

E.g., if in `A1` you had the full path in correct format without single quotes, this formula would work:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!K52")
```

[image]

Comment: what if cell A1 only contains till filename and I have to define sheet names in the cell itself, how does that work?

Comment: If `A1` contains `C:\Temp\[test_file.xlsx]`, then your formula will be `=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "Sheet1'!K52")`

Comment: thanks, you are a life saver

Comment: For this, do we have to open the file? If I do not open the file then it shows #REF error

Comment: Yea, this is how Excel works as far as I know. You can try asking a new question about such case. It would be nice to find a workaround.